# Avoid axis being cut when brushing

Tags: javascript, d3.js, brush

Ok I have this brushed code in D3

```
    function brushed() {
  x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
  focus.select(".line").attr("d", line);
  focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/DtvCerKdeDs9jklZo5QY?p=preview

that is based on this brushing example

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367

Instead of an area I plot a line. My problem is that I want to avoid the y axis being cut by the blue line when I brush.
Someone knows how to solve this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed applying the clip-path to your line path:

```
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1 px;
  stroke-opacity: 0.8;  
  clip-path: url(#clip); //<-- Apply clip-path to path
}
```

Updated [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/gDsHxT0Gkc5hZg4h0Pzm?p=preview).